# I have a problem in the latest version of anaconda when I use ETABS OAPI. I received the message "Cannot open file \\ BufferFileIn::BufferFileIn()"

Tags: python, anaconda, buffer

I don't know what happen when I installed Anaconda in a computer to run my code, it comes with Python 3.8.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au7tB.jpg)
I changed from Python 3.8 to 3.6 but the problem is still there. I run the same code in another computer and this message don't appear. The code is running but when I take the time needed to solve the same proble in another computer and it increases when this message appear.
I 'm running a lot of models and the code have to write and read models in each itteration. How I said the same code in another computer don't show this message.  ¿Is there some package I have to change?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use images to post code or error message unless the image is conveying something more than the code or error message. If you need to you should augment the image with the text it contains because images of text are not searchable, accessible, and they make it harder for people trying to help you. Please read also [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I think the error is because you have never run the model through your python code in that computer, so the code can't find the files that the code makes after you run the model.

My solution was run each model through my python code and the message error didn't appear anymore (because the file.Y now exist). Hope it works to you